# Get jQuery to do action only once when using window.scroll

Tags: jquery

I have code below which reads window height and will do one action when less than 50% scrolled and another when scrolled more than 50% - this works fine - BUT, it repeatedly does the action after the scroll fires so ends up repeating the action thousands of times when scrolling - How can I modify this to just call once, then not again until the scroll height changes to the other threshold?

Code example here shows the problem - view the console.log to see the reoccurring actions

```js
( function($) {
                
        function homeMCformSwitching() {
            
            var t=$(window).scrollTop()+1; 
            var c=$('html').outerHeight(); 
            var p=(t/c*100).toFixed(0); 
            
                
            if (p<50) { 
            console.log("do action for top half");
            }
            if (p>50) {
            console.log("do action for bottom half");
            }
             
        }
        
        homeMCformSwitching();
        $(window).scroll(function() { homeMCformSwitching(); });
    
    })(jQuery);
```

```css
div { height: 3000px; background: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
Check console to see the log firing many times over and over on scroll
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to store the last action you did when a scroll threshold is reached. So that on subsequent scrolls with the same threshold you can skip the same action.

Example:

```
( function($) {
    
        var previousWidth = jQuery(window).width();
        /** changed here **/
        let lastAction = 0;
        function homeMCformSwitching() {
            
            var t=$(window).scrollTop()+1; 
            var c=$('html').outerHeight(); 
            var p=(t/c*100).toFixed(0); 
            
            /** changed here **/    
            if (p<50 && lastAction != -1) {
            lastAction = -1;
            console.log("do action for top half");
            }
            /** changed here **/
            if (p>50 && lastAction != 1) {
            lastAction = 1;
            console.log("do action for bottom half");
            }
             
        }
        
        homeMCformSwitching();
        $(window).scroll(function() { homeMCformSwitching(); });
    
    })(jQuery);
```